Filter large database DynamoDB
I do have a large data with 3,00,000 entries, I need to filter out the 5 attribute with pagination of limit 100,
also I have a static partition key "index_field": 1 , so now how can I fitter out the data, currently dynamoDB Filter is applied after the limit is reached, so you are only guaranteed ~100 items, not exactly 100, after that dynamoDB returning me a empty array with LastEvantualKey.

Thats how DynamoDB works, using a FilterExpression is not efficient and should be avoided if you are dropping the majority of your items, which you are.
I suggest you revisit your data model, perhaps include some of those attributes as key values to make your requests more efficient.
If you can't do that, I would suggest leveraging a relational database like Aurora.
